# Using C++ unmanaged class in C# class library

Tags: c#, c++, import, unmanaged

How can I import a class from a C++ unmanaged project and use it in a C# class library? 
The solutions I have seen worked in execute projects.
Are there any step by step guides?

Answer (score 2):

A **native** C++ class can't be directly consumed from C#/.NET code.

You can wrap the native C++ class using a tiny **C++/CLI interop layer**, and then use that from C#.

Or you could build a **COM** wrapper around the native C++ class, and consume the COM component from C#.

Another option would be to build a **DLL with a pure C interface**, wrapping the native C++ class, and then consume that C-interface DLL from C# using P/Invoke.